# Stuck on making a list of sudoku block values? [Python]

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a list of sets of sudoku subblock indices given puzzle length N. Here's a diagram to perhaps better articulate what I'm getting at.

```
00 01 02|03 04 05|06 07 08 
09 10 11|12 13 14|15 16 17 
18 19 20|21 22 23|24 25 26
--------+--------+-------- 
27 28 29|30 31 32|33 34 35 
36 37 38|39 40 41|42 43 44 
45 46 47|48 49 50|51 52 53
--------+--------+--------
54 55 56|57 58 59|60 61 62 
63 64 65|66 67 68|69 70 71 
72 73 74|75 76 77|78 79 80
```

A set for the top leftmost subblock of a 9x9 sudoku grid would look something like {0, 1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 18, 19, 20}.

However, as of right now, I've been hard-coding these subblocks and they only work for 9x9 puzzles. I would like to write a function to create the list of sets for any NxN puzzle, but I'm stuck.

Here's my code so far:

```
  finalList = []
  subblockList = [[] for i in range(27)]
  for i in range(9):
    for j in range(3):
      subblockList[i].append(i * 9 + j)
    for j in range(3):
      subblockList[i + 9].append(i * 9 + 3 + j)
    for j in range(3):
      subblockList[i + 18].append(i * 9 + 6 + j)
  for i in range(0, 27, 3):
    finalList.append(set(subblockList[i] + subblockList[i + 1] + subblockList[i + 2]))
  print(finalList)
```

Comment: What does a whole list look like?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Please share your example code for the 9x9 case and people may be able to suggest ways to generalise for nxn (and m sized subblocks)

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: edited for clarity + code

Comment: @voyage1970 I think you've still somewhat missed Grismar's question on how you need to partition the resulting grid.. Are you always partitioning into 9 sets and therefore N will always be divisible by 3, will you divide a NxN grid into MxM partitions where M divides N evenly, or will you allow uneven divisions of N where not all sets are the same size? ie: what do you do with a 10x10 grid?

Answer (score 1):

I assume we want N^2 x N^2 grid split into N^2 subgrids each of N^2 x N^2. Ie for N=3 we split 9x9 grid into 9 subgrids, etc

The question is not about Python but Pandas allow for a succinct answer.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
N=3 # test as in standard sudoku
cols = list(range(N*N))
idx  = list(range(N*N))
data = np.array(range(N**4)).reshape((N**2, N**2))
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols - np.mod(cols,N), data = data, index = idx - np.mod(idx,N))
```

This creates a 9x9 grid indexed by groups of 3s:

```
|    |   0 |   0 |   0 |   3 |   3 |   3 |   6 |   6 |   6 |
|---:|----:|----:|----:|----:|----:|----:|----:|----:|----:|
|  0 |   0 |   1 |   2 |   3 |   4 |   5 |   6 |   7 |   8 |
|  0 |   9 |  10 |  11 |  12 |  13 |  14 |  15 |  16 |  17 |
|  0 |  18 |  19 |  20 |  21 |  22 |  23 |  24 |  25 |  26 |
|  3 |  27 |  28 |  29 |  30 |  31 |  32 |  33 |  34 |  35 |
|  3 |  36 |  37 |  38 |  39 |  40 |  41 |  42 |  43 |  44 |
|  3 |  45 |  46 |  47 |  48 |  49 |  50 |  51 |  52 |  53 |
|  6 |  54 |  55 |  56 |  57 |  58 |  59 |  60 |  61 |  62 |
|  6 |  63 |  64 |  65 |  66 |  67 |  68 |  69 |  70 |  71 |
|  6 |  72 |  73 |  74 |  75 |  76 |  77 |  78 |  79 |  80 |
```

now we stack, so the column index becomes a subindex of rows, and then group

```
df2 = df.stack()
df2 = df2.groupby(df2.index)
```

Finally, we extract sub-grids

```
subgrids = [list(grp[1].values) for grp in df2]
subgrids
```

here is what we get

```
[[0, 1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 18, 19, 20],
 [3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23],
 [6, 7, 8, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26],
 [27, 28, 29, 36, 37, 38, 45, 46, 47],
 [30, 31, 32, 39, 40, 41, 48, 49, 50],
 [33, 34, 35, 42, 43, 44, 51, 52, 53],
 [54, 55, 56, 63, 64, 65, 72, 73, 74],
 [57, 58, 59, 66, 67, 68, 75, 76, 77],
 [60, 61, 62, 69, 70, 71, 78, 79, 80]]
```